# vscode classpath: Import all jar in folder

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, classpath

I would like to import all jar files into my vscode project classpath.
If I do this it works, but only for one library of course:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mylib.jar"/>
```

In my case I have almost 100 .jar files to import. If I put them in lib and put try this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib"/>
```

Or this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/*.jar"/>
```

Or this

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/*"/>
```

Do not work

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Start from Language Support for Java@0.55.0,you could add new setting `java.project.referencedLibraries` to config the project classpaths.

like:

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
   "library/**/*.jar",
   "/home/username/lib/foo.jar"
 ]
```

refer to this [link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/1196#issuecomment-568192224)

Comment: try to change `"library/**/*.jar"` to  `"lib/**/*.jar"`

Comment: Yes i tried. It doesn't work. Actually the only thing that work is if I input manually the .jar into the .classpath. Thank you